# How to manipulate HTML in a Facebook post

Tags: html, facebook

Is there anyway that I can manipulate HTML in a Facebook post? Is it possible to edit the code in anyway without having to install a third-party app?

Answer (score 1):

Sure, depending on which browser you are using, there are different ways. Just search for dev tools [your browser] and you will find a way. Guess it's mostly F12. 
Of course that's just locally, you won't be able to change the data on the server, if you're not allowed to.

Answer (score 0):

Right Click > Investigate or F12 on the Element you want to edit and on your right there should open the code you can freely edit it to your liking

Also when posting on SO please provide more than just saying i want to do that.. How to do it? Tell us what you have tried or where you have researched before asking the Question